# Loading an image from AWS S3 bucket as a thumbnail

Tags: macos, amazon-s3, nstableview, nsimagecell

My Mac OSX app uploads images from the mac to AWS S3. I'm trying to load a table of images from files on the AWS S3 bucket. I don't want to download  the image on the desktop PC but just load it as a thumbnail on the NSTableView for viewing. Is there any S3 methods to load the image content  from the AWS S3?

Comment: umm... if you're trying to display thumbnails of the images you've already uploaded, why not just make a tiny NSImageView of the image on your local disk and not download it from AWS?  Or, why are you talking about "desktop PC's"?  are you talking about how to download the images on *other* computers beyond the one that did the uploading?

Comment: ok i sound wrong here. I'm uploading the pic at different instance. its a mac osx app and if i upload a pic now and close the app, am I going to save that imageview content somewhere (like core data) so next time when i open i can access it?